# Running camera without a screen

Tags: android

Can we run camera on android without a display screen? How to bypass permission required for Camera on API 23+ ? I am beginner here.

Answer (score 1):

There's extensive examples here:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

To sum up, it's more similar to iOS now. You ask for permission when it's required. I doubt that you can "bypass" the check though. If your app needs the camera, it has to ask for it. If it doesn't need the camera, don't ask for it.

And remember to tell the user why you need the permission.